# Ejabberd - Server Configuration for public connection

Tags: configuration, xmpp, ejabberd

I have a linux server.

I installed ejabberd on the server.

I can go into administration url - `http://ipaddress:5280/admin`

I can not connect via jabber client to the server.

How do I set up a server for public connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure:

a) You do not firewall the ports.
b) You have valid [SRV records](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records) for your domain, for example,

```
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 5222 server.example.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 5269 server.example.net.
```