# XMPP SRV Records on Mac os x

Tags: dns, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using erlang 17, ejabberd 14.07 on mac os x. I am running ejabberd on localhost.I can not connect via jabber client to the server. I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058106/ejabberd-server-configuration-for-public-connection).

According to thread I should have valid SRV Records, But I don't know SRV Records Concept, So do anyone have any idea what to do to have valid SRV Records on mac os x?

Comment: Can you please give reason for down vote?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided with any errors, or something to help you with. Also, the thread you mentioned refers to a problem with a public connection, you are running on locally.

SRV records describe which services and on which port are running on the server you are trying to connect to (in your case localhost).
But, SRV records are set to the DNS server, are you running any DNS on your Mac OS X?

For more information about SRVs look here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record